# Assembly, Reading characters in a 'loop' fails upon comparison under certain input

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

I'm writing a 64bit GAS assembly program; it's supposed to read one character from stdin. If the character is a capital 'A', the program terminates. If it's not a capital A, the program should loop back to the beginning and read another character. This is the program:

```
.section .data
    mychar: .byte 0x0

.section .text
.global main
main:
###Get Input###    
    mov $0, %eax            # specify read syscall
    mov $0, %edi            # param1: input stream (stdin)
    mov $(mychar), %esi     # param2: recvevd ptr
    mov $1, %edx            # param3: # of chars 2 read
    syscall

###Check if typed character is a 'A'###
    sub $65, mychar         # subtract 'A' ascii code
    jne main

    mov $60, %eax           # graceful termination syscall
    mov $0, %edi            # return code
    syscall
```

Now, here's the problem: the program works for the first inputted character, but for any subsequent characters, the capital 'A' check always fails.

```
Example Input:
A 
#program terminates, as expected

Example Input:
j
s
f
A   #program should have terminated, but just continues reading input
s
a
```

I've tried debugging with GDB, but I haven't noticed anything suspicious (I'm a bit of a newbie :). Any insight appreciated.

Comment: In at&t syntax you should specify byte size for the subtract as `subb $65, mychar`. I am surprised it even assembles as-is, but looks like it picks `long` as default.

Comment: thanks @Jester, it works now. One letter does make a difference, wow!

Comment: @Jester The GNU assembler should warn you if it cannot infer the operand size. Perhaps OP neglected to show us the warning or his gas version somehow doesn't do that.

Comment: Yeah it should but mine (`GNU assembler GNU Binutils for Debian 2.22`) doesn't either. Apparently it only does so for `mov`. Go figure.

Comment: @travisjayday sure, in assembly every letter counts, like forgotten `$` ahead of constant gives AT&T syntax completely different meaning (I find it actually quite hard to read, any particular reason why you are learning GAS syntax instead of Intel syntax (which is IMO a tiny bit more human-friendly)?)

Comment: @fuz the GCC assembler assembled as quiet as a mouse, no warnings, no nothing. If it had shown some warnings, I bet I could've figured it out myself. Also, I assemble my filename.s with GCC filename.s -no-pie,  if that makes a difference

Comment: @Ped7g, I'm learning GAS syntax mainly because all the Unix tools use it and most of the references/guides I've come across use it too. So it appears to be easier to learn, even though it's harder to read. What a paradox! :)

Comment: If you plan to write assembly by hand, then I would personally use different tools (nasm and edb-debugger are my personal favs). The gcc/gdb/objdump mainline of tools can be switched to intel syntax too, but I wouldn't use it like that to write code. It's ok for debugging/disassembly, but compiling non-native syntax ... don't know, I would refrain from that, feels fragile. But having good tutorial/docs source is also essential, so if you can't find good resources, maybe stick to GAS (just my personal taste shrugs, IMO that syntax is not for humans, just machines and tools).

Comment: Thanks @Ped7g for the tips, guess I'll give Intel syntax another shot. I've tried using it before with GCC & GDB but as you said, it did seem very fragile and sometimes it just didn't work out (the GCC Intel syntax is peculiar). Now that I know the basic concepts of assembly in GAS, I can probably find & understand nasm Intel syntax resources better.